# How to access a common variable in .ts and .scss file

Tags: typescript, sass, angular8

When a user logs into an app, a client id is generated and, based on that client id, I want to implement a stylesheet theme in scss for that client to be used in an Angular application—but only after they logon, at which point I will know which client is logged in.

I am trying to use `@if… @else` conditions in scss based on the client id value, but I am unable to access the variable which I have stored the value of the client id in the TypeScript file.

Alternatively, if there is any other way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Is the client ID being _generated_ for each user when they create their account? Or is an existing client ID being _assigned_ to a user when they create their account? If the former, on what basis are you setting style sheet information? E.g., does the user have a profile which allows them to configure style information? And, if so, where is that data being stored? In a database? Session? Cookie? This will help us better understand your use case, and thus what problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: It’s worth noting that in _most_ scenarios it doesn’t really make sense to use a client side variable like a client ID in your SCSS file, as _usually_ your SCSS (and your TypeScript) are _precompiled_, and thus can’t be dynamically altered at runtime. Instead, if you need to dynamically generate a style sheet, you’d usually do that using e.g. JavaScript, or a server side framework, to generate CSS. More commonly, though, you’d establish CSS classes which alter the appearance of the site, and which can be applied to your markup dynamically based on who is logged in.

Comment: thanks Jeremy to respond. The client id is stored in session store from there i am using that id in ts file and i want to compare that id where is client1 or client2.

Comment: Aha, so the client ID is not _unique_ to a user, but instead users will be _assigned_ to client1 or client2 when they log in? In that case, usually, you’d one of two approaches. The first is to have classes prefixed with the client ID in your SCSS (e.g., `.client1 { .class { … }}`) and then dynamically assign the client I’d as a class on your `body`. The second is to generate an independent CSS file per client, and then dynamically reference that style sheet per user.

Comment: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/build-truly-dynamic-theme-with-css-variables-539516e95837 This Post helped me a lot in a similar situation. CSS Variable was my answer.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to implement second approach but failing to get the reference of file as per the client, like i am new in angular and don't know how to do it.If you have any idea regarding this please guide me through this.